# Prove a Recursive Formula by Induction?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, recursion, recursive-algorithms, formal-proofs

So I have a bonus question on a homework assignment I am working on that literally just asks "How would you prove a recursive formula by induction?" There are no numbers, or sequences given.

I understand how to prove something using induction, but am very confused on how to go about doing it for a recursive formula.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do it exactly as you would for any other kind of formula.

Comment: what a peculiar homework assignment. Not sure how the procedure differs

Comment: The assignment is for the student to *demonstrate* their own understanding of the proof by induction, and to gain better understanding through *practice*.

Answer (score 0):

Your mission, if you choose to accept it, is to outline the steps involved in proving by induction that $\forall k\geq 0:a_k = g(k)$ when given that $a_0=c$ and $\forall k\geq 0:a_{k+1} = f(a_{k})$.

That is how do you prove $a_k=g(k)$ is the closed form of the recursion formula.

---

As you understand what proof by induction involves, what is the first thing you would do?

> So if I was looking at a regular non recursive formula, I would test the base case, which would be 0, and see that it works.

That's the exactly right thing to do.   So, do that then.

Okay, what *is* the base case here?

> Then assume that its true for k, and try to prove that its true for k+1.

Yes, and *what* are you assuming is true for any $k$ here?

Likewise *what* do you need to prove for $k+1$.

> It is very easy for me with a regular problem, there is just something about a recursive formula that makes it seem much more confusing

It should not be *that* confusing.   It is just a matter of identifying how to use the recursion formula to move from the assumption to the required conclusion.

---

- "First I would test the base case, which is:" ...
- "Then I would assume that for some $k$: the premise holds, which is:" ...
- "Using this assumption I would demonstrate that for $k+1$ we have: " ...
- "The recursion formula would be used to show this since:" ...

Comment: This is really throwing me off. So if I was looking at a regular non recursive formula, I would test the base case, which would be 0, and see that it works. Then assume that its true for k, and try to prove that its true for k+1. It is very easy for me with a regular problem, there is just something about a recursive formula that makes it seem much more confusing.

Comment: @JebusCrust That is okay. Just go through step by step. (1) What is the base case, (2) what do you need to assume, (3) what do you need to prove, (4) how would recursion be used to do that?

Answer (score 0):

An example. The Fibonacci numbers. $F(0)=0.\;$ $\;F(1)=1.$ Recursively, $F(n+2)=F(n+1)+F(n).$ Prove, by induction, the formula $$F(n)=(a^n-b^n)/\sqrt 5,$$ where $a=(1+\sqrt 5)/2\;$ and $\;b=(1-\sqrt 5)/2.$

Note that $a$ and $b$ are the solutions to $x^2=x+1.$ So $a^2=a+1 $ and $b^2=b+1.$

So if the formula is valid for $n$ and for $n+1$ then $$(a^{n+2}-b^{n+2})/\sqrt 5=[a^n(a^2)-b^n(b^2)]/\sqrt 5=$$ $$=[a^n(a+1)-b^n(b+1)]/\sqrt 5=$$ $$=[a^{n+1}-b^{n+1}]/\sqrt 5\; +\; [a^n-b^n]/\sqrt 5=$$ $$=F(n+1)+F(n)=F(n+2).$$ Then confirm that the formula is valid for $n=0$ and for $n=1.$